# JS Event Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, authentication

I just started developing a Firebase PWA and I was having issues with my authentication code.  I am getting the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null`.  I think the error has something to do with the page loading in, but I'm not sure, and I'm also unsure of how to fix it.  I already put the code within a function, but I still get this error.  (I also cut out the part where I initialize firebase, but its in the function).

```
  btnLogin.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const email = txtEmail.value;
    const pass = txtPassword.value;
    const auth = firebase.auth();
    //sign in
    const promise = auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass);
    promise.catch(e => console.log(e.message));
  });
  //Sign Up
  btn.SignUp.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const email = txtEmail.value;
    const pass = txtPassword.value;
    const auth = firebase.auth();
    //sign in
    const promise = auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass);
    promise.catch(e => console.log(e.message));
  });
```

Comment: The message is fairly clear - you're trying to call `addEventListener` on something that's null.  There's not enough information here to know why that is.  You'll have to do some debugging to figure out what is null and where that came from.

Comment: Are you sure `btn.SignUp` is correct and not just `btnSignUp`? Else `btn` would have to be an object containing `SignUp`, which I kinda doubt.